# Best platform supported for implementing anti-spamming?

Tags: database, nosql

I have to maintain below mentioned schema where i would be having records of 50 million users(rows) and i need to get the records as well as update the records count on every get operation for that particular record.

**SCHEMA:**
project_id | domain_id | user_id | type | subtype | epoch_day | count

what platform should be used for efficiently querying on such a schema (efficiency both in terms of time and space is required) moreover it would be good if the platform supports ttl as well so that the records get deleted once they are expired.

**QUERY:**

Get count where userId = x, project_id = x,  domain_id = x,  type = x, subtype = x for 1 last day

Get count where userId = x, project_id = x,  domain_id = x,  type = x, subtype = x for last 7 days

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated, my use case is to implement Anti-spamming.

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet answer to your question. You need to use some kind of database, and either one will not give the best results if you query the schema the way you described it. That conclusion is simply because you are going to use multiple keys and so multiple index scans will not be very optimal either way.

What you could do is optimize the data for the kind of query that you are trying to execute. One option would be to combine all the key values into one new key and use that to query. e.g., a new key can contain the concatenated value of `userId + project_id + domain_id + type + subtype + date`. After you do this trick, you have a single key that you can index and get the maximum query performance. When querying, concatenate all the search values together and find the rows by their keys.

Based on the number of rows, any relational database can handle it. If you want to take that to the next level, consider sharding the data via one of the NoSQL databases so that the query only scans a subset of the information and not the entire dataset. Although, as I said, the number of rows that you mentioned sounds very feasible for a single scan.

As about deletions, you need to either find very specialized platform that deletes based on the expiration or write one by yourself. The latter is always an accessible trick - write a script or a job that deletes all expired rows, let's say, once a day.

That is what I would do.

I know that I didn't mention any specific platform, because in your case, I think that the platform will not make a significant difference.